# Add permission to all authenticated users

Tags: 2013, permissions, office-365

I have a Site Collection in our SharePoint online tenant. I wanted to give Read permission for everybody in our organization. so in Site Permissions I Clicked on `Grant Permissions` and typed `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` and clicked ok. However nobody has access to the site collection yet. I thought I have to add `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` to the members group but still nobody has access to the Site Collection.

Comment: Are you using ADFS for authenticating users?

Comment: I don't know I have to ask. I will be back. Does it matter?

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users will only work on-prem. If you type in "All" you should get suggestions to the correct claims user token for all users, for example "All authenticated users" :)

Comment: I got two suggestions, All users(windows) and All users(Membership). which one is right?

Comment: Probably membership, depends on your setup with authentication. Also this quote " put in a support ticket with Microsoft and found out that our users (who all are external to our network and use Windows Live IDs to authenticate) cannot be included in any kind of "all users" authentication.  I have to enter them all individually into the Visitors group." from http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/79019.aspx seems to indicate that you can not add external users in any "All...", just a side note

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can provide permissions to following groups :

1. All Authenticated Users: All user accounts which can be recognized by SharePoint Online, both for internal and external.
2. All Users (Windows) : User accounts from Federated domains.
3. [image]All Users (membership): All user accounts from Office 365 Online Services.

Comment: To add to this, there's also 'Everyone' and 'Everyone except external users'

Answer (score 8):

`Everyone` was what worked for me

***EDIT***
Everyone is a default group that contains all authenticated and guest users that can connect to your network.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, with details on how your problem got solved..

Comment: can we do this in a event receiver in sp2013? i tried with nt authority \authenticated user, but ti didnt work. please let me know everyone will work