# Give Permission to Another Members

Tags: permissions, site-collection

I created new site collection. I want to share the site collection to other members.

I add to "Everyone" in the .../Members groups. But other members can't see.  Where should I give authority to another?

Comment: Do you mean SharePoint Online or on-premises?

Answer (score 1):

Add "NT Authority\Authenticated Users" to the members group, not Everyone

If you are using SharePoint Online, look at this
[Add permission to all authenticated users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/add-permission-to-all-authenticated-users)

Comment: I don't understand this solve. When I add users in members, image does not come with me on the links.

Comment: I didn't understand your above comment, write `NT Authority\Authenticated Users` and press Ctrl+K to resolve the user name.