# Allow all SharePoint users to access to site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions, site

I created SharePoint site for all employees in my company (a few thousands people). For now every user, who is not added manually to site group cannot get access to site. He can of course send request to me but this is annoying.

My goal is to allow every SharePoint user from my company to get access to whole my site by default, without sending request and adding singular user to certain group. I am looking for someting like a group for *'Other Users'*, a container for every SharePoint user, who is not a member of any other group. I need also to give certain credentials for these *'Other Users'* members (Contribute without permission to delete list items).

Do you know how can I attain it in SharePoint 2013 Online? I don't have access to Central Administration tools.

Comment: sharepoint site anonymous access 2013 http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-sharepoint-site-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Anonymous access will give anyone access, but everyone in the user access will give the org wide access but not anyone outside the domain. So as a security practice (unless if the site is public facing website / needs anonymous access) this anonymous access is not recommended.

Comment: I don't have this icon on my ribbon so I think that Anonymous Access is disabled for all SharePoint sites in my company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "Everyone" that will give all user access. also when you give access you can assign appropriate permission on that, Should this help you let me know.

Or if you more concerned you can give NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users

Because The "Everyone" group is a superset of the authenticated users group. It includes the Authenticated Users group and the Guest account..

Reference: [Authenticated Users Group vs the Everyone Group](http://windowsitpro.com/security/authenticated-users-group-vs-everyone-group)

[Thread on Authenticated users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/add-permission-to-all-authenticated-users)

Comment: Thanks. "Everyone" will give access for only internal (my company) users or also for external users, who don't have SharePoint account in my company?

Comment: @tm_  Please read this post which will give you clear idea https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/add-permission-to-all-authenticated-users